# shell script if condition giving error message in openshift platform . if[ == ] : not found [No such file or directory ]

Tags: shell, kubernetes, openshift

I've implemented script like below:

```
podName=someValue ; // Here value is dynamic (empty or non empty)

if[ $podName == " "] then

 echo "Empty"
```

Even though I got empty an output but still could see:

```
if[ == ] : not found [No such file or directory ]
```

error message while running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a small formatting issue which is causing this error. This should be the correct code.

```sh
podName=someValue

if [ "$podName" == " " ]; then
    echo "Empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string is empty in **bash / sh** like this (some containers don't have bash shell):

```
podName="someValue"

if [ -z "$podName" ]; then
  echo "Empty"
fi
```

or:

```
podName="someValue"

if [ "$podName" = "" ]; then
  echo "Empty"
fi
```

The following syntax works only in bash `[ "$podName" == "" ]`